# Why is $z^4-1-i=0$ a polynomial equation which does not have real coefficients?(complex-number)

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

Why is $z^4-1-i=0$ a polynomial equation which does not have real coefficients? Its coefficient is $1$ and $1$ is a real number, isn't it?

Comment: If this polynomial is $az^4+bz^3+cz^2+dz+e$, what do you think $a,b,c,d,e$ are?

Comment: Its coeffcients are a,b,c,d and e is the constant ....actually,  I didn't know the constant also has a coefficient before I saw the answer below.

Comment: A meal consisting of 4 dishes is not called a vegetarian meal if 3 of the dishes are made exclusively from vegetables and  the fourth item is chicken.

Comment: Your polynomial is $\color{Red}{1}z^4+\color{Red}{0}z^3+\color{Red}{0}z^2+\color{Red}{0}z+ \color{Red}{-1-i}$. The coefficients are in red.

Comment: @user236116 it helps noting this can be written as $az^4+bz^3+cz^2+dz^1+ez^0$ taking the convention z^0=1 for z=0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constant term is $-1-i$, which is not real.  That is one of the coeffcients.